# What is the meaning of calling an Abstract method inside an abstract class?

Tags: java, abstract

I came across a piece of code where there is a call to an abstract method ? I was just curious to know what it means ? Meanwhile the class is being called from a non-abstract method.

Comment: Can you please explain more?

Comment: For this you must first read what is an abstract class and what is an abstract method.

Comment: Actually I know about abstract classes and their use but I could not understand why an abstract method was called from within an abstract class.

Answer (score 3):

When you implement an abstract class you will also implement a concrete class. In the concrete class all abstract methods of the abstract class need to be implemented.

When a method in the abstract class call an abstract method, it refers to the implementation of this method in the concrete class.

```
public abstract class A {
    public String method() {
        // do something
        int i = abstractMethod(); // abstract method call
    }

    public abstract int abstractMethod();
}

public class B extends A {
    public int abstractMethod() { // <-- this implementation of the method is called.
        return 1;
    }
}

public class C extends A {
    public int abstractMethod() { // <-- this implementation of the method is called.
        return 100;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new B();
        a.method(); // -> abstractMethod of class B is called

        a = new C();
        c.method(); // -> abstractMethod of class C is called
    }
}
```

Comment: I have another question say if there are more than 2 classes extending class A in the above case then which implementation of abstractMethod() will be called ?

Comment: You cannot instantiate an abstract class. You need to instantiate a concrete derived class. Therefore the method of the concrete class you instantiated will be used.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you. It would be great if you accepted my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

An abstract method is a method that belongs to an abstract class but has no implementation which means that it has to be implemented (or overridden) by any children of the abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

That is the whole idea of an abstract method / class: It allows the developer to define the behavior of the class later.

Assume, your class requires to "load some resource", but you want to provide different implementations for that task. Then you can override the abstract method with either loading a resource over the network or from the file system etc.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

Answer (score 0):

An abstract method is a method inside an abstract class or an interface. It has no body, and one must be defined by a subclass before it can be instantiated. This allows interface classes that define some common methods, but leave some to the implementations.

The abstract methods can be called from non-abstract ones, because:

1. They are non-static, so they need an instance of that class to be called.
2. An instance of that class may not exist if the method hasn't been implemented, as the resulting class would also be abstract.
3. Therefore a caller will always have an instance of a class implementing that method.